# Making sure a function is only binded once in a JQuery Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have written a very simple JQuery widget to handle fixed toolbars:

```
(function($){
$.fn.stickytoolbar = function(options){
    $(window).bind(
        'scroll resize', function(){
    });
}
})(JQuery);
```

Now the problem I have is that everytime I say `$('.something').stickytoolbar()` it will potentially bind the window event again and again because `$(window)` is in the global scope.
Is there anyway there to make sure that the bind on the window only occurs once no matter how many of the stickytoolbar widgets I make?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I knew there was something :), I'll accept when it lets me